# Getting Build Errors in Program to Change Button Name When Clicked

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Class MyButtonClass
    Inherits Form

    Private mrButton As Button
    Public Sub MyButtonClass()

        mrButton = New Button()
        mrButton.Text = "Click me "
        mrButton.Click += New System.EventHandler(MyButtonClickEventHandler)
        Me.Controls.Add(mrButton)
    End Sub
    Shared Sub Main()
        Application.Run(New MyButtonClass())
    End Sub
    Private Sub MyButtonClickEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        mrButton.Text = "You clicked me!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: to format code, select it in the editor and press Control-K. On the other hand, don't just post a bunch of code and expect someone here to solve all your problems for you. You don't even say what error you're seeing!

Comment: Mr Button. I don't remember him from [the series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Men)

Comment: Will Do It From Now onwards and I am new to It will learn, and I am not here so that people will solve all my problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing C# and VB.Net code.

```
mrButton.Click += New system.EventHandler(MyButtonClickEventHandler)
```

Is C# syntax.

The button handler should either be declared as:

```
Private Sub MyButtonClickEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles mrButton.Click
```

Or you use the `AddHandler` as:

```
AddHandler mrButton.Click, AddressOf MyButtonClickEventHandler
```